# how to find web address of a tomcat web app?

Tags: tomcat, url, grails

I am trying to debug why a url that used to work before is giving page not found error. So, i have access to a ubuntu linux machine where this app resides. When i list the running services i can see that tomcat server is running. I have also tried restarting the server to make sure the problem is not in the app.  I am wondering how can i find the web address to this web app? I know how to find global ip address of this machine but i need to know the full path so that i can access this webapp. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The URLs in a Grails application are mapped to controllers or views via the UrlMappings.groovy file.  In a Grails 2.x version the file is located under the conf directory and in a Grails 3.x it is under the init directory (in the lastest version 3.2.2 it is a package under the init directory).